# Google Cloud Python Lib - Get Entity By ID or Key

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, entity

I've been working on a python3 script that is given an Entity Id as a command line argument. I need to create a query or some other way to retrieve the entire entity based off this id.

Here are some things I've tried (self.entityId is the id provided on the commandline):

```
entityKey = self.datastore_client.key('Asdf', self.entityId, namespace='Asdf')
query = self.datastore_client.query(namespace='asdf', kind='Asdf')
query.key_filter(entityKey)
query_iter = query.fetch()
for entity in query_iter:
    print(entity)
```

Instead of `query.key_filter()`, i have also tried:

```
query.add_filter('id', '=', self.entityId)
query.add_filter('__key__', '=', entityKey)
query.add_filter('key', '=', entityKey)
```

So far, none of these have worked. However, a generic non-filtered query does return all the Entities in the specified namespace. I have been consulting the documentation at: https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/queries.html and other similar pages of the same documentation.

Comment: Is the entity you are trying to find a top level entity or could it be anywhere in your hierarchy?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean here, but the entity is located in a namespace of the same name (but lowercase first character). Beyond the namespace, there is no hierarchy. The namespace is just a big flat bucket of entities.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler answer is to simply fetch the entity.  I.e. `self.datastore_client.get(self.datastore_client.key('Asdf', self.entityId, namespace='asdf'))`

However, given that you are casting both entity.key.id and self.entityId, you'll want to check your data to see if you are key names or ids. Alternatives to the above are:

- You are using key ids, but self.entityid is a string `self.datastore_client.get(self.datastore_client.key('Asdf', int(self.entityId), namespace='asdf'))`
- You are using key names, and entityId is an int `self.datastore_client.get(self.datastore_client.key('Asdf', str(self.entityId), namespace='asdf'))`

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this problem myself. Because I could not get any filter approach to work, I ended up doing a query for all Entities in the namespace, and then did a conditional check on entity.key.id, and comparing it to the id passed on the commandline.

```
    query = self.datastore_client.query(namespace='asdf', kind='Asdf')
    query_iter = query.fetch()
    for entity in query_iter:
        if (int(entity.key.id) == int(self.entityId)):
            #do some stuff with the entity data
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very easy to do, although not so clear from the docs.

Here's the working example:

```
>>> key = client.key('EntityKind', 1234)
>>> client.get(key)
<Entity('EntityKind', 1234) {'property': 'value'}>
```